# Are/were cowboys mostly known for wearing blue jeans in the Spanish-speaking culture?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

In Twain's *Adventures of Huckleberry Finn*, "Blue jeans britches" is translated as "pantalones vaqueros azules"

In the US, I believe it was first miners who wore blue jeans most often; was it cowboy attire in Spanish-speaking countries?

Comment: I don't know very well what you mean by your question, but absolutely no Spanish people or people from any South American country wear blue jeans in their traditional clothing.

Comment: I thought US cowboys wore chaps not jeans.

Comment: I have only heard jeans called *vaqueros* in Spain, where cowboys never existed.

Comment: The translation is good.

Comment: Comentario aparte. Por décadas en Chile a los jeans se les conocía exclusivamente como _pecosbiles_. Los abuelitos de 80 años o más todavía les dicen así.

Comment: @Rodrigo ¿Pecosbiles?! Qué vocablo tan extraño. Tendré que indagarle el origen...

Comment: I think it's for [Pecos Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pecos_Bill)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a chain of associations at work here. First, the cowboy tradition of the American West was actually derived from the tradition of the Mexican *vaqueros*, in turn brought from Spain. These *vaqueros* and their counterparts the American cowboys wore woolen pants with tight waists. Wool was later replaced by canvas, and rivets were added to the pockets to prevent tearing. Later still, canvas was replaced by denim, the material chosen by Strauss and Davids for their “blue jeans”. During all this time and through these changes, evidently, cowboys and their pants were closely linked in the popular mind,  so that the pants were called *vaqueros* in Spanish. The popularization of Westerns cemented this link.

I have no idea what *britches* meant in Twain's time or in that particular book, but I don't think Twain was thinking of cowboy attire, and therefore *pantalones vaqueros* would not be a good translation, since the expression evokes the image of (modern) blue jeans or the kind of thing a cowboy in a Western would wear.

Comment: Que yo sepa, *britches* son ropa interior.

Comment: @nopaltepec I think they are regular trousers, especially ones which end at or above the knee. There is also the concept of riding breeches (britches is a variant spelling). Of course what Twain thought they were is anybody's guess.

Comment: We always just used "britches" as a synonym for pants (I grew up in rural California in the 50s and 60s)

Comment: https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=britches&qpvt=britches&form=IGRE&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover

Comment: britches is an old-fashioned word for pants or trousers.